# connection string not working online but working ofline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Please help this is working offline but when uploaded to the **VPS server** it's not working.

```
string conn = Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xxx,49170\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=UserName;
Password=Pass;Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=true;Connect Timeout=20
```

Comment: `xx.xxx.xx.xxx,49170\SQLEXPRESS` doesn't sound right. Are you using SQL Express in Production?

Comment: What error are you getting?